# Reading key pressing from a keyboard in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know about "a = gets", but I need to read characters from keyboard without pressing enter.
How can I do this in ruby?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946738/detect-key-press-non-blocking-w-o-getc-gets-in-ruby

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174933/how-to-get-a-single-character-without-pressing-enter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the green_shoes gem or simply use red shoes, here a green_shoes working sample

```
 ['green_shoes'].each(&method(:require))
Shoes.app do
 e = edit_line
 info = para "NO KEY is PRESSED."
 keypress do |k|
   info.replace "#{k.inspect} was PRESSED."
   print k
 end
end
```

Works on any OS unlike the sollution from [Detect key press (non-blocking) w/o getc/gets in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946738/detect-key-press-non-blocking-w-o-getc-gets-in-ruby)
Put your shoes on !

Comment: Nifty! Thanks for sharing this - it's very different and a neat approach.

Comment: thanks, i advise to ta a good look at green shoes, it's amazing what you can do with it, could you accept my answer please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the STDIN, please check its document. 
It's a powerful tool to control your standard input .