# ruby webdriver: how to catch key pressed while the script is running?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'm opening a set of URLs with a WebDriver in ruby – kind of a slideshow with 3 seconds  intervals between "slides" (pages). Person looking at that happening might click Space, and I need that page URL saved to another file. How could I handle those interruptions – catch the event of Space pressed?

```
require "watir-webdriver"

urls = [...list of URLs here...]
saved = []

b = Watir::Browser.new

urls.each do |url|
  b.goto url
  sleep(3)

  # ...what should I put here to handle Space pressed?

  if space_pressed
    saved << b.url
  end
end
```

Comment: Where would you expect the space to be pressed? Do you mean in the browser or maybe the command prompt running the script?

Comment: @justin-ko: either will work for me. I tried solution offered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946738/detect-key-press-non-blocking-w-o-getc-gets-in-ruby but wasn't able to catch any keys pressed in the browser (nothing happens) or command line (it displays pressed keys, but with no effect on the script running).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem might be solvable with STDIN.getch.

If you create a file with the following script and then run it in a command prompt (eg "ruby script.rb"), the script will:

1. Navigate to the url.
2. Ask if the url should be captured.
3. If the user does not input anything in 10 seconds, it will proceed onto the next url. I changed it from 3 since it was too fast. You can change the time back to 3 seconds in the line `Timeout::timeout(10)`.
4. If the user did input something, it will save the url if the input was a space. Otherwise it will ignore it and move on.

Script:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
require 'io/console'
require 'timeout'

urls = ['www.google.ca', 'www.yahoo.ca', 'www.gmail.com']
saved = []

b = Watir::Browser.new

urls.each do |url|
  b.goto url

  # Give user 10 seconds to provide input
  puts "Capture url '#{url}'?"
  $stdout.flush
  input = Timeout::timeout(10) {
    input = STDIN.getch
  } rescue ''

  # If the user's input is a space, save the url
  if input == ' ' 
    saved << b.url
  end
end

p saved
```

A couple of notes:

- Note that the inputs need to be to the command prompt rather than the browser.
- If the user presses a key before the allotted timeout, the script will immediately proceed to the next url.

Comment: Justin, could you think of any way to make it let's say down-arrow instead of Enter to go to the next URL? And - yes, some one key ("s" for example as a shortcut for "save") instead of s-Enter could have been so much nicer. I probably will need to find a way for $stdin to expect only one key, and not (some_entry)+Enter.

Comment: Okay, after some more digging, I found some core libraries that can be combined to do what we need (ie no longer needs enter key). Try this updated answer.