# Exit command examples

Tags: ruby, command, exit

I want to press a key at any point, causing the simulation to stop without loosing data collected until that point. I don't know how to do the exit command. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: @WandMaker That does not save the data.

Comment: Catching an interrupt, as @user1934428 describes below, is easy. But we can't really help you beyond that that without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, WandMaker's comment tells only half of the story.

First, there is no general rule, that Control-C will interrupt your program (see the for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764434/1934428)), but assume that this works in your case (since it will work in many cases):

If I understand you write, you want to somehow "process" the data collected up to this point. This means that you need to intercept the effect of Control-C (which, IF it works as expected, will make the controlling shell deliver a SIGINT), or that you need to interecept the "exit" (since the default behaviour upon receiving a SIGINT would be to exit the program).

If you want to go along the first path, you need to catch the `Interrupt` exception; see for example [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Interrupt.html).

If you want to follow the second route, you need to install an [exit handler](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit). Note that it will be called too when the program is exited in the normal way.

If you are unsure, which way is better - and I see no general way to recommend one over the other -, try the first one. There is less chance that you will accidentally ruin something.

Comment: ok, my code is for example this:
def countdown(i)

 return if i.zero?
   puts i
   sleep 1
   countdown(i-1)
   
end

countdown(25)

and I want to be able to stop the program... have a one button (S or whatever) and when I press the "S" during the program, it wil stop running.

Comment: `def countdown(i)

 return if i.zero?
   puts i
   sleep 1
   countdown(i-1)
   
end

countdown(25)`

Comment: If you don't want to intercept SIGINT, as I suggested, you can - inside your loop - check for whether a key has been pressed. There is a good discussion on this topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/946738/detect-key-press-non-blocking-w-o-getc-gets-in-ruby). Be sure to read the whole thread, because the details depend on which OS you are.